# sql query to get Result Table from Table A and Table B

Tags: mysql, database

Please check tables below and help to solve.
Table A

| a_id | name | dept | a_date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Clark | Sales | 2024-01-01 | 5000 |
| 124 | Clark | Sales | 2024-01-02 | 6000 |
| 125 | John | Sales | 2024-01-03 | 3500 |
| 126 | John | Sales | 2024-01-04 | 5500 |

Table B

| b_id | name | dept | b_date | amount | status | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | Clark | Sales | 2024-02-05 | 1000 | Paid | Loan |
| 2002 | Clark | Sales | 2024-02-06 | 1000 | Unpaid | Loan |
| 2003 | Clark | Sales | 2024-02-08 | 5000 | Paid | Loan |
| 2004 | Clark | Sales | 2024-02-09 | 1000 | Unpaid | Adv |
| 2005 | John | Sales | 2024-02-11 | 1000 | Unpaid | Loan |

Result Table for Name "Clark"

| Date | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 | +5000 |
| 2024-01-02 | +6000 |
| 2024-02-05 | -1000 |
| 2024-02-08 | -5000 |
| Total | +5000 |

- Row 01 and 02 in Result Table -> name = Clark from Table A
- Row 03 and 04 in Result Table -> status = 'Paid' AND type = 'Loan' AND name = 'Clark' from Table B

I have tried coalesce and many other solutions here but I am unable to achieve this.

Thanks

I have tried coalesce, inner join, CASE and many other solutions here but I am unable to achieve this.

Comment: To me, it looks like you need a UNION. How do you get column **Sr. No.** in the result table?

Comment: I will try UNION, Column Sr. No. deleted from Result Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the criteria described in your question, I suggest a UNION.

```sql
SELECT a_date as `Date`
      ,amount
  FROM table_a
 WHERE name = 'Clark'
UNION
SELECT b_date as `Date`
      ,amount
  FROM table_b
 WHERE name = 'Clark'
   AND status = 'Paid'
   AND type = 'Loan'
```

Note that DATE is a reserved word in MySQL, hence in the above code it is enclosed in backticks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT \
    a_date as `Date`,
    amount
FROM table_a
WHERE name = 'Clark'
UNION
SELECT 
   b_date as `Date`,
   amount
FROM table_b
WHERE name = 'Clark' AND status = 'Paid' AND type = 'Loan'
```

About the negative values, on your description you have only positive values. If you are storing positive values and want to use PAID UNPAID to make this as credit or debit, you can use the IF function

`IF(status == 'Unpaid', amount*-1, amount)`