# Ledger Table from two tables in mysql query

Tags: mysql

Please check tables below and help to solve.
Table A

| a_id | name | dept | a_date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Clark | Sales | 2024-01-01 | 5000 |
| 124 | Clark | Sales | 2024-01-02 | 6000 |
| 125 | John | Sales | 2024-01-03 | 3500 |
| 126 | John | Sales | 2024-01-04 | 5500 |

Table B

| b_id | name | dept | b_date | amount | status | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | Clark | Sales | 2024-02-05 | 1000 | Paid | Loan |
| 2002 | Clark | Sales | 2024-02-06 | 1000 | Unpaid | Loan |
| 2003 | Clark | Sales | 2024-02-08 | 5000 | Paid | Loan |
| 2004 | Clark | Sales | 2024-02-09 | 1000 | Unpaid | Adv |
| 2005 | John | Sales | 2024-02-11 | 1000 | Unpaid | Loan |

With the help of this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78114022/21144944)
I tried below query.

```
SELECT
   a_date as `Date`,
   amount as `Paid Amount`,
   0 as `Received Amount`,
   amount - 0 as `Balance`
FROM `Table A`
WHERE name = 'Clark'
UNION
SELECT 
   b_date as `Date`,
   0 as `Paid Amount`,
   amount as `Received Amount`,
   0 - amount as `Balance`
FROM `Table B`
WHERE name = 'Clark' AND status = 'Paid' AND type = 'Loan'
ORDER BY `Date` ASC
```

Which gives table as below.

| Date | Paid Amount | Received Amount | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 | 5000 | 0 | 5000 |
| 2024-01-02 | 6000 | 0 | 6000 |
| 2024-02-05 | 0 | 1000 | -1000 |
| 2024-02-08 | 0 | 5000 | -5000 |

but I am trying to achieve Result table like this

| Date | Paid Amount | Received Amount | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 | 5000 | 0 | 5000 |
| 2024-01-02 | 6000 | 0 | 11000 |
| 2024-02-05 | 0 | 1000 | 10000 |
| 2024-02-08 | 0 | 5000 | 5000 |

In Column `Balance` every cell will be SUM with previous cell

First Row -> 5000

Second Row -> 5000 + 6000 = 11000

Thirst Row -> 6000 - 1000 = 10000

Fourth Row -> 10000 - 5000 = 5000

Any hint and solution is highly appreciated.
Thanks
Update: fourth row updated as suggested by @akina

Comment: `SELECT @@version;` = ?

Comment: Why `b_id=2003` is not counted?

Comment: thanks for pointing out mistake, I just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this query works for me

```
SELECT `Date`, `Paid Amount`, `Received Amount`, @balance:= @balance + (`Paid Amount` - `Received Amount`) AS `Balance` FROM (SELECT a_date AS `Date`, amount AS `Paid Amount`, 0 AS `Received Amount` FROM `Table A` WHERE `name` = 'Clark' UNION ALL
SELECT b_date AS `Date`, 0 AS `Paid Amount`, amount AS `Received Amount` FROM `Table B` WHERE `name` = 'Clark' AND `status` = 'Paid' AND `type` = 'Loan') AS sub JOIN (SELECT @balance := 0) AS balance_init ORDER BY `Date` ASC;
```

Comment: thanks a lot @taranjeet-singh its working absolutely perfect.